# How do i prevent the player from dragging an image outside the specified area?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to drag an Image in a certain area. For that I am using IDragHandler. To prevent the image to go outside the area, i put four box colliders in a square shape. The box was still moving out. So, I put the fixed timestep to 0.0001. Now, when the image goes out of boundry, it pushes back the image in the specified area which is fine but I want the image to stop moving out the boundary the moment it touch the edge of the image.
Here's my code:

```
public class Draggable : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler
{
    public GameObject box;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("Triggered");

    }


    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        box.transform.position = eventData.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Did you tried using ```Mathf.Clamp()``` ?

Comment: Please show us the full code of what you tried ... I see no pushing back ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t use physics and fixed timestep to solve this problem. It is performance killer to reduce timestep.

One way to do it : use Physics.OverlapBox ( see documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html)

Do this test between your draggable object and the limit of your draggable zone in your OnDrag method. Calculate the « Wanted » position base on the event you receive and if your object overlap with your borders then dont move it, if not your are safe and you can move it.

Comment: Thanks for your response Flavien Marianacci. You are right, fixed timestep is not the right way to solve this problem and it would have reduced the performance. I tried the physics overlapbox and it worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to achieve your bounderies as simple numbers. Maybe create a rectangle and take its corners. Then you get the best user experience by using min and max functions, effectively "clamping" the allowed coordinates before they are actually set.
It makes sense to clamp x and y separately. That way the user can still drag along the Y axis if there is room despite the mouse being outside the boundary on the X axis.

Comment: Thanks for your response AlexGeorg. Create rectangle by what? Can you please show the code.